# Create a redirect that removes a segment from a URL

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm changing the URL structure on a site and need to set a 301 to force users to the new URL.

I want to go from:

```
http://website.com/blog/single/name-of-entry
```

to:

```
http://website.com/blog/name-of-entry
```

I'd like to remove the segment `single`.

I've been searching, but haven't found anything that's worked yet. I think I've gotten close with this code:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?single(.*)$ /$1$2 [L]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(.+?)/single/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=301]
```